# Find the lengths of the segments that are formed when the angle bisectors intersect the median in a right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> The angle bisectors $AL$ and $BQ$ in the right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle ACB=90^\circ$ and catheti $15$ and $20$ divide the median $CM$ into three segments. Find their lengths.

I am not sure how to approach the problem. The most "obvious" thing that we can do is to find the hypotenuse $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=25$ of the triangle $\triangle ABC$. Therefore, $m_c=\dfrac12 \cdot 25=12.5$. On my sketch $AC=15$ and $BC=20$. What to do next?

Comment: Do you know the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, I do!..];.

Comment: Then I assume you can easily solve the problem. :)

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't realise that $AP$ is also an angle bisector in $\triangle ACM$ and $BT$ is an angle bisector in $\triangle BCM$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $CM\cap AL=\{P\}$ and $BQ\cap CM=\{T\}$.

Thus, $$\frac{CP}{PM}=\frac{AC}{AM}$$ and 
$$\frac{CT}{TM}=\frac{BC}{BM}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I got it! Thank you! Can I ask you if $P$ lies on $CT$? I am just trying to find in what order are the points indeed on $CM$.

Comment: @LYI I got $CP=\frac{75}{11}$ and $TM=\frac{125}{26},$ which says $P$ lies on $CT$.